# I've been working on this code and I get the following error

Tags: python-3.x, gauss

This code is for the gauss elimination that works with a matrix and I can't understand why the following error appears on screen.

```
def elimGauss(A,m,n):
    for k in range(n-1):
        for i in range(k+1,n):
            p = -A[i][k] / (A[k][k])
            for j in range(k,n):
                if (k == j):
                    A[i][j] = 0
                else:
                    A[i][j] = A[i][j] + (p * A[k][j])
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Solange/Desktop/Trabajo Final Fund. Programacion - Eliminacion Gauss.py", line 42, in <module>
    elimGauss(M,3,3)
  File "C:/Users/Solange/Desktop/Trabajo Final Fund. Programacion - Eliminacion Gauss.py", line 29, in elimGauss
    p = -A[i][k] / (A[k][k])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: None-Type error during iteration with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851028/error-none-type-error-during-iteration-with-python)

Comment: Without seeing what `M` is , we can't help. You should read [mcve].

Comment: What is `A`. What is `m`. What is `n`? We need an [MCVE]. Error is self explanatory - you want to do `None[something]` and `None` does not support this operation.

Comment: Should remove the 'gauss' tag from this question as this is not the GAUSS programming language.